# Unable to find the TF executable while adding tfs to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I am adding TFS to Visual Studio Code IDE(1.42.0) for that I have installed **`Azure Repos`** extension.

In VS code at  `File-->Preference-->Setting-->Tfvc:Location`, when I am entering path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe`.

Getting error

> (team) Unable to find the TF executable. Please ensure TF is installed
>   and the path specified contains the filename.

How can I solve this issue?

**Edit 1:** After installing *Azure Repos* extension, I am entering above path in tfvc:Location(for both tabs User and Workspace), but after entering path nothing happens. Check below screenshot

[image]

**Edit2:** Now I am getting this error at right below in VS code IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not got any help yet. I will take a shot. Any chance there is a issue with finding the executable and casing for the extension? My local TF is capitilized. `\TF.exe`

Also might want to checkout the Github and readme for [TFVC](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed VS on your computer. With a typical installation of Visual Studio, the Windows version of the TFVC command line client (tf.exe) is available under the `Program Files (x86)` folder. It will typically be placed in a location similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe`. On the 2017 version of Visual Studio Community, it can be found in a location similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe`.

Comment: In setting (tfvc:Location) when I am entering ts.exe file path nothing happening. I have VS Enterprise and latest VS code.

Comment: Do you use VS 2017 Enterprise? Have you checked `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`?

Comment: Yeah I have VS Enterprize 2017. This is my path I am using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe`

Comment: Have you checked the path? Is the TF.exe there?

Comment: Yes. TF.exe file is there.

Comment: Please double check whether you have added the correct entry to the setting "tfvc.location": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe".

Comment: Have you tried using double slash \\ sometimes vs code doesn't find windows path with just a single \ (ps it's a linux thing).  or you can change all the \ for / (single) that works on both linux and windows.  Also try the comment from below with TF.exe (capitalized).

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya After entering path, it's expected nothing happens. You should be able to use TFVC function now. Do you still get any error?

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya Are you able to use the TFVC function now?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - Now I am starting adding tfs to VS Code. is `Azure Repos` extension fine?

Comment: Yes. I've tested it when you posted this case and it's working.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - After adding path  followed by file name  I am getting error. Please check my updated question screenshot.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - Could you please check my updated question.

Comment: Did you get the error after input the Location? Did you change your workspace from Server to Local? Can you try to disable the extension and enable again?

Comment: Yes I got error, please check Edit2 in my question. Now I am getting error `(team) It appears you are using a Server workspace. Currently, TFVC support is limited to Local workspaces.` How to change workspace from server to local?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-and-server-workspace-how-can-i-tell-which-one-im-working-with

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - I have changed workspace to local. tfs getting connected for few seconds(at bottom left) when I open VSC and suddenly showing error(at bottom right) `(team) It appears you are using a Server workspace. Currently, TFVC support is limited to Local workspaces.`

Comment: Try to create a new local workspace, and reinstall the extension.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - I have created new work space also but no changs..Just getting conected(after teams login) and disconnected

Comment: Did you reinstall the extension? You would also need to disable and enable the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found a .vscode folder in my project
delete it, close and reopen vscode solved the problem